# How to extract the array inside the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, fetch-api

```
const html = test.map((user) => {
    return `
    <div class="user">
    ID: ${user.labels.id}
    </div>
    `;
document.querySelector("#app").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
```

API URL : https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js/issues

There's an array inside the object which is labels. And I want to try to extract the object inside "labels" array. But since the method I use only work if it's an object, how to do it if it's an array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: There are multiple objects inside the array. Which one do you want?

Comment: `user.labels[0].id` will get the first one. `user.labels.map(label => label.id)` will get an array of all of them.

Comment: i thinked of using another looping for it but for weird reason I can't think how to use it. That really hit the spot. Thanks alot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const html = 
test.map((user) => {
return `
${user.labels.map((label) => {
return `
<div class="label">
Labels:<br>
ID: ${label.id}<br>
Node ID: ${label.node_id}<br>
</div>
`;
})}
</p>
</div>
`;
})
.join("");
console.log(html);
document.querySelector("#app").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
```

Comment: I don't see what you've changed in the code snippet.

Comment: i didn't realize i copy+paste the old code